# How do I convert my working PHP script to CryptoJS to access a remote API?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cryptojs

I have the following PHP script which works perfectly in accessing a remote REST api. Ultimately I give it a query along the lines of `?fromDate=2020-07-22` and it generates a final URL which returns the XML based on that response. My problem is that I have tried to convert it to Javascript so that I can get it working in a Node application (I am new to Javascript and know next to nothing about JQuery!!). I cannot for the life of me get it working. The problem I believe lies with passing the query `fromDate` `2020-07-22` into the parameters which is required to generate the correct footprint that needs to be included in the final REST api request so that it can be correctly authenticated.

I have included the original working PHP script below and my efforts of making a JS equivalent. I've been working on this for hours now, and my brain has finally given up!

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```php
<?php
$publicKey  = "insert public key here";
$privateKey = "insert private key here";
$url = 'https://www.api_endpoint.com/rest/1.0/reports?fromDate=2020-07-22';
$finalUrl = generateSignedUrl($url, $publicKey, $privateKey);
 
echo $finalUrl;
 
function generateSignedUrl($url, $publicKey, $privateKey) {
    $urlParts = parse_url($url);
    parse_str($urlParts['query'], $parameters);

    $parameters['myWebServiceID'] = $publicKey;
    $parameters['timeStamp'] = time();
    $parameters['footprint'] = generateFootPrint($privateKey, $parameters);
 
    return sprintf('%s://%s%s?%s', $urlParts['scheme'], $urlParts['host'], $urlParts['path'], http_build_query($parameters));
}
 
function generateFootPrint($privateKey, $parameters) {
    if (empty($parameters)) throw new InvalidArgumentException('Parameters cannot be null');
 
    $parameters["secretKey"] = $privateKey;
    unset($parameters["footprint"]);
    ksort($parameters);
    $queryString = http_build_query($parameters);
    return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $queryString, $privateKey, true));
}
?>
```

And here is my JS version:

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/hmac.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/sha1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/sha256.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/enc-base64.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

var url = 'https://www.api_endpoint.com/rest/1.0/reports?fromDate=2020-07-22'; //Where I append my query
var publicKey = 'insert public key here';
var secretKey = 'insert private key here';
var timestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000);
      
var parametersToHmac = {
    "myWebServiceID": publicKey,
    "secretKey": secretKey,
    "timeStamp": timestamp,
    "fromDate": '2020-07-22' //Where I last attempted to insert the query manually
};

var stringParametersToHmac = jQuery.param(parametersToHmac);
var hash_hmac = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(stringParametersToHmac, secretKey);
var base64 = hash_hmac.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
      
var finalResult = {
    "myWebServiceID": publicKey,
    "timeStamp": timestamp,
    "footprint": base64
};
      
var finalQueryParams = jQuery.param(finalResult);
var finalUrl = url + "?" + finalQueryParams;
console.log(finalUrl);
```

I have tried putting the query in manually and various attempts to parse it but am struggling with the concept of where it needs to be inserted to ensure that the footprint is generated correctly and therefore not rejected by the endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it's quite amazing how once you've asked a question it helps to clarify what you have done wrong. In the PHP script in the generateFootPrint function there is a ksort function which sorts the keys alphabetically within PHP. I had missed this in my translation to Javascript.

Therefore changing the parameters passed to Hmac:

```js
var parametersToHmac = {
    "myWebServiceID": publicKey,
    "secretKey": secretKey,
    "timeStamp": timestamp,
    "fromDate": '2020-07-22' //move this from here
};
```

to:

```js
var parametersToHmac = {
    "fromDate": '2020-07-22', //to here!!
    "myWebServiceID": publicKey,
    "secretKey": secretKey,
    "timeStamp": timestamp
};
```

i.e. alphabetically by key, returns an identical footprint to the PHP script, and when compiled into a rest URL is accepted by the endpoint and returns the data needed.

Thanks for listening!

Comment: Glad you managed to solve it yourself!! Something we use at work to help us find issues in code is Rubber Duck Debugging (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), which it sounds like you did by asking this question - just sharing in case you find it useful in future dev endeavours! :)

Comment: @Luke, that is exactly what happened.:)